# How can I properly test a component which is an Apollo GraphQL query?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jestjs, enzyme

I have a situation where I am getting frustrated after some hours of working on the same test. I have a query component which returns a `datatable`. That component I tested it already and it has 100% test coverage.

The test claims to be missing coverage on lines 42, 145, 148, 151 (see the component below to see notes about the lines).

If you look until the end of the component it claims for coverage on some actions handlers.

But now I am testing its parent component which is this:

```
// imports

const GetShipments = ({
  t,
  shipmentsPaginationHandler,
  toggleFiltersModalHandler,
  isFiltersModalOpened,
}) => {
  const removeFilterConst = filterKey => () => {
    removeFilterHandler(filterKey);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <TableToolbarComp
        toggleFiltersModal={toggleFiltersModalHandler} // LINE 42
        isFiltersModalOpened={isFiltersModalOpened}
        removeFilter={removeFilterConst}
      />
      <Query
        query={GET_SHIPMENTS}
        variables={{
          ...filters,
          shippedDate: filters.shippedDate,
          limit: pagination.pageSize,
          offset: (pagination.page - 1) * pagination.pageSize,
        }}
        context={{ uri: `/this?url=${softlayerAccountId}` }}
      >
        {({ loading, error, data }) => {
          let tableRowsModel;
          let itemsCount;

          if (error) {
            return (...);
          }

          if (loading) return (...);

          if (data && data.GetShipments) {
            ({ itemsCount } = data.GetShipments);

            if (data.GetShipments.shipments) {
              tableRowsModel = data.GetShipments.shipments.map(row => ({
                ...row,
                id: `${row.id}`,
                type: row.type.name : '',
                status: row.status ? row.status.name : '',
              }));
            } else {
              tableRowsModel = [];
            }

            setCSVDataHandler(data.GetShipments);
          }

          return (
            <ShipmentsTable tableRows={tableRowsModel} />
          );
        }}
      </Query>
    </>
  );
};

GetShipments.propTypes = {
  // propTypes validation
};

export default compose(
  connect(
    store => ({
      softlayerAccountId: store.global.softlayerAccountId,
      isFiltersModalOpened: store.shipments.filtersModalOpened,
    }),
    dispatch => ({
      removeFilterHandler: filterKey => {
        dispatch(removeFilter(filterKey));
      },
      toggleFiltersModalHandler: () => {
        dispatch(toggleFiltersModal()); // LINE 145
      },
    }),
  ),
  translate(),
)(GetShipments);
```

The most I create tests it seems to be just ignoring what I am doing.

This is what I have so far:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MockedProvider } from 'react-apollo/test-utils';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import { Provider as ReduxProvider } from 'react-redux';
import GetShipments from '../../containers/GetShipments';
import createMockStore from '../../../../utils/createMockStore';

import store from '../../../../redux/store';

import mocks from '../../__fixtures__/shipments-mock';

jest.mock('react-i18next', () => ({
  // this mock makes sure any components using the translate HoC receive the t function as a prop
  translate: () => Component => {
    Component.defaultProps = { ...Component.defaultProps, t: key => key }; 
    return Component;
  },
}));

describe('Container to test: GetShipments', () => {
  let props;

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
      t: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      softlayerAccountId: 123,
      isFiltersModalOpened: false,
      toggleFiltersModalHandler: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      setFiltersHandler: jest.fn(() => k => k),
      removeFilterHandler: jest.fn(() => k => k),
    };
  });

  it('should render without errors', () => {
    mount(
      <MockedProvider
        mocks={mocks.filter(mock => mock.id === 'get-shipments-default')}
      >
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          <GetShipments
            {...props}
            store={createMockStore({
              global: {
                accountGuid: 'abcd-1234',
                softlayerAccountId: '1234',
              },
            })}
          />
        </ReduxProvider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    );
  });

  it('should render loading state initially', () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={[]} addTypename={false}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          <GetShipments {...props} />
        </ReduxProvider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    );

    expect(wrapper.find('DataTableSkeleton')).toHaveLength(1);
  });

  it('should render data', async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
          <GetShipments store={store} {...props} />
        </ReduxProvider>
      </MockedProvider>,
    );

    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve));
    await wrapper.update();

    console.log(wrapper.debug());
  });

  it('should NOT render any data', () => {
    mount(
      <MockedProvider mocks={[]} addTypename={false}>
        <GetShipments store={store} />
      </MockedProvider>,
    );
  });
});
```

So what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you seem to be missing assertions in a number of your tests. Is this purposeful? For example, I'd expect you to be using a snapshot assertion in your first test case ("it should render without errors"). The only test case that's asserting something is "should render loading state".

Regarding the missing coverage, without seeing the full Jest test report, I'm going to simply presume that the functions you've highlighted are never running, i.e. you're not testing that `dispatch(toggleFiltersModal())` is running when you execute `toggleFiltersModalHandler`. In order to achieve 100% test coverage, you need to test these functions. As you're using Enzyme, this could be as simple as:

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
            <GetShipments store={store} {...props} />
        </ReduxProvider>
   </MockedProvider>
);

wrapper.props().toggleFiltersModalHandler();
```

Unfortunately, as you are using HOCs, you will most likely have to `find` your component before you can execute the function on the prop, like so:

```
const wrapper = mount(
    <MockedProvider mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}>
        <ReduxProvider store={store}>
            <GetShipments store={store} {...props} />
        </ReduxProvider>
   </MockedProvider>
);

wrapper.find(GetShipments).props().toggleFiltersModalHandler();
```

You'll no doubt have to do some trial and error to find the prop in your wrapper, but once you've found it, simply execute it and assert that the function has executed using a jest spy.